# Kubernetes EBS/EFS mount and attach issue while creating pod in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I am using CSI driver utils for EFS and EBS within my EKS cluster. Somehow, while trying to create a pod to test, it appears that my pod is stuck within the container-creation state with the following error messages in Events.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age    From                                                      Message
  ----     ------       ----   ----                                                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled    3m28s  default-scheduler                                         Successfully assigned default/app1 to zzzzzz.compute.internal
  Warning  FailedMount  85s    kubelet, zzzzzz.compute.internal  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[persistent-storage], unattached volumes=[persistent-storage default-token-6dxfr]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  34s    kubelet, zzzzzz.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "efs-pv" : rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

For clarity of the process I followed, I used the following articles to deploy the csi driver.

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

Once done, I tried deploying the pods at

git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver.git

cd aws-efs-csi-driver/examples/kubernetes/multiple_pods/

*$ cat specs/pv.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-xxxxxxx
```

*$ cat specs/storageclass.yaml*

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
```

*$ cat specs/claim.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

The pod definition, which I deployed last is as follows.

```
$ cat specs/pod1.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app1
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /data/out1.txt; sleep 5; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: persistent-storage
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: persistent-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: efs-claim
```

This did provide the mentioned event errors.

Any idea about what I am missing. As the pods are placed successfully, believe this is nothing to do with the taints or tolerations.

Comment: `kubectl get pv,pvc`  o/p may be helpful here.

Comment: Yeah checked claims is bound to the pv

`efs-claim   Bound     efs-pv   5Gi        RWX            efs-sc`

`efs-pv                                     5Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    default/efs-claim                                    efs-sc`

Comment: check https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/192

Comment: Hi @Pasan Chamikara, Could you please run `kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep efs-csi-controller` and make sure that `efs-csi-controller-` pods are running?

Comment: Those were running @MikolajS.

Comment: @PasanChamikara I've got the same issue, have you found a solution?